# How to make bootable Windows 10 install USB on Vista

Tags: windows-10, usb, installation, iso-image, bootable-media

I have a Windows Vista laptop that I want to upgrade to Windows 10. I went to the Windows 10 download page (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and I followed the instruction to downloaded a Windows 10 Fall Creator Update ISO. But I did not find instruction to make Windows 10 Install USB.

I then searched around the web and found links of MediaCreationTool.exe from Microsoft. I downloaded the file but it will not run, complaining it is not a valid Win32 Application. I double checked that I am downloading a 32-bit version. No dice.

Then I read the instruction again and realize that the Windows 10 download page mentioned a tool which is only available on Windows 7, 8.1 and 10. Sure enough, when I open the link on Windows 7. It let me download the MediaCreationTool.exe. It is the exact same file I found earlier but it runs on my Windows 7 (which happens to be 64-bits).

But after running the Media Creation Tool, I could not get it to use the .iso file that I previously downloaded. I am currently using a metered and slow internet connection and I could not afford to download the 5GB ISO again. Is there a way to make Windows 10 USB using the Media Creation Tool? I would prefer to stick to this official tool as much as possible.

Comment: Have a look at this bad boy https://rufus.akeo.ie/ or do what I did and search Google (other search engines are available) for "create bootable usb from iso"

Comment: You understand there is no migration path from Vista to Windows 10 which means, you will have to do a clean installation of Windows 10, which means your personal files, applications, and settings will be lost.  I suggest just downloading the ISO, booting to it, and installing Windows 10 since you had problems with the Media Creation Tool